# Jenkins Test Report URL Intermittently Broken

Tags: jenkins

Sometimes Jenkins is producing broken URLs for test reports.

The really odd part is it's doing it intermittently: for a given build number it works, then a few minutes later I'll look and it'll be producing a broken link. I restart Jenkins, and the link is correct again.

On the page `/job/My%20Job/lastBuild/testReport/` there's a table with Maven submodules listed (only one in my case). The link anchor is the name of the module, and the URL when it works is `http://jenkins:8080/job/My%20Job/com.company.product$product-soapui/17/testReport/`.

When it doesn't work that link is `http://jenkins:8080/testReport/`.

I'm quite perplexed at the intermittent nature of the issue.

**UPDATE**

Jenkins version: 1.529

OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)

Comment: Jenkins version and OS please

Comment: What happens if you update the version of Jenkins to the latest weekly or LTS release.  Does this problem still exist?